# Why do my variables all disappear in this method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a deck of cards with the `CardController` class.

The Card class (unseen) represents individual cards and comes with the constructor `public Card(String cardValue, CardType cardType)`.

My deck of cards is filled out correctly until my `deckIndexTracker` hits 10, at which point the code moves to a switch statement to fill out the card values

> Jack, Queen, King and Ace.

After using Eclipse's debugging tool, I find that every single one of my variables vanish after the method goes past `deckIndexTracker` 9.

What could be going on here?

```
public class CardController {
    public static Card[] makeDeck() {//2 to 10 + J,Q,K,A
        Card[] deck = new Card[51];
        int deckIndexTracker = 1;
        while(deckIndexTracker <= 13) {
            if(deckIndexTracker <= 9) {
            deck[deckIndexTracker - 1] = new Card(String.valueOf(deckIndexTracker + 1), CardType.HEART);
            deckIndexTracker++;             
            }else {
                switch(deckIndexTracker) {
                case 10:
                    deck[deckIndexTracker - 1] = new Card("Jack", CardType.HEART);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    deck[deckIndexTracker - 1] = new Card("Queen", CardType.HEART);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    deck[deckIndexTracker - 1] = new Card("King", CardType.HEART);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    deck[deckIndexTracker - 1] = new Card("Ace", CardType.HEART);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You increase `deckIndexTracker` only `if is true`. Why don't use `int deckIndexTracker = 0` and remove that `-1` from index of `deck`?

Comment: Shouldn't this be an infinite loop?

Comment: `deckIndexTracker`is not incremented if its value is > 9

Comment: Recommend using a `for` loop instead of explicitly incrementing your index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you are going about this the wrong way to begin with.  Instead of using a `switch` statement when constructing the deck, it would make more sense to use the `switch` in the constructor for the `Card`.  `Card` can then handle different cases inside of the constructor easily which will make your code a lot more reusable.

The `Card` class would look like this:

```
private String cardVal;
private CardType suit;

public Card(int value, CardType suit){

    switch(value)
    {
        case 1:
        case 14:
            this.cardVal = "Ace";
            break;
        case 11:
            this.cardVal = "Jack";
            break;
        case 12:
            this.cardVal = "Queen";
            break;
        case 13:
            this.cardVal = "King";
            break;
        default: //Default case that handles nonface cards
            this.cardVal = String.valueOf(value);
    }
    this.suit = suit;
}
```

Then look how easily you can build the *entire* deck with every suit:

```
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int deckIndexTracker = 2; deckIndexTracker <= 14; deckIndexTracker++)
    {
        deck.add(new Card(deckIndexTracker, CardType.HEART));
        deck.add(new Card(deckIndexTracker, CardType.CLUB));
        deck.add(new Card(deckIndexTracker, CardType.SPADE));
        deck.add(new Card(deckIndexTracker, CardType.DIAMOND));
    }
```

Use constructors to your advantage!  I even put a case where `Ace` is used for both `1` and `14`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while loop` looks like is an infinite loop, because you stop increasing `deckIndexTracker` value after 10.

You can make your code more simple. Using just switch:

```
int deckIndexTracker = 2; 
//start from 2, 
//because the case where value is equal with 9
//you add new Card("9 + 1",...) which should be "Jack" in my opinion.
//start from 2 -> add value of index in Card, but remove 2 at deck index.

while(deckIndexTracker <= 13) {

    switch(deckIndexTracker) {

        case 10:
            deck[deckIndexTracker - 2] = new Card("Jack", CardType.HEART);
            break;

        case 11:
            deck[deckIndexTracker - 2] = new Card("Queen", CardType.HEART);
            break;

        case 12:
            deck[deckIndexTracker - 2] = new Card("King", CardType.HEART);
            break;

        case 13:
            deck[deckIndexTracker - 2] = new Card("Ace", CardType.HEART);
            break;

        default:
            deck[deckIndexTracker - 2] = new Card(String.valueOf(deckIndexTracker), CardType.HEART);
            break;

    }

    deckIndexTracker++;

}
```

If you use `deckIndexTracker` only for this part of your code, I recommend to use `for loop`:

```
for(int deckIndexTracker = 2; deckIndexTracker <= 13; deckIndexTracker++){

    switch(deckIndexTracker){

        //same like in while

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `deckIndexTracker++` at the end of your else statement so it continues on and doesn't stop at the Jack. Or, you could add it at the end of the while loop and remove the one that is inside your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the value of `deckIndexTracker` in `if()` so once control goes to `else` part, the variable is not increased.

Add

> deckIndexTracker++;

after `if-else` in `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with above code is the position of #deckIndexTracker++;. It is in if block.
Upto deckIndexTracker=9, it will work properly. Once deckIndexTracker=10 it will come to else block and there deckIndexTracker count will not be increased and it will remain 10. Due to which it will become infinite loop.
Solution : Place #deckIndexTracker++; after if-else block